# Laravel mock Model partical

Tags: laravel, mockery

I have a method in my User Model class called `getBlabla`. Now i want to mock this method via

```
$this->partialMock(User::class, function ($mock) {
           $mock->shouldReceive([
               'getBlaBla' => 'some data',
           ]);
});
```

But then i get always some errors because Mockery change my class name, and therefore also the convention for tables and relation columns.

```
General error: 1 no such table: mockery_3__app__users
```

Of course i want to use the Eloquent methods in my User Model. But want only to mock this `getBlaBla` Method.

Comment: What are you doing in `getBlaBla` actually? Please provide more code, so we can understand your issue..

Comment: This method only returns a simple string. I want to mock and change the return value. Nothing special here.

Comment: Your method only returns a simple string? Then, why it's complaining about `table`? Seems not make sense to me..since I can't reproduce your issue..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way?

```php
$mock = m::mock('User')->makePartial();
$mock->shouldReceive("getBlaBla")->once()->andReturn("some data");
```

I'm more familiar with this last syntax, I think it should work this way.